# How to dynamically retrieve the value of an input type "url" and put it in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input of type "url" that has a placeholder.

The user has to complete that url.

I would like to get the value that the user entered, put it in a variable

and then use it in my script.

Here is my html

```
`<input type="url" name="input1" value="https://myWebApplication.com/logs/">`
```

here is what I tried to do using Jquery but I always get the initial value of the placeholder instead of the newly entered URL.

```
`var newURL = "";
 $("input").keyup(function() {
    newURL = $(this).val();
 }).keyup();`
```

I'm unable to retrieve the newly inserted value.

Comment: Why? That seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nauzilus/0w05bgkm/ (I'm just using `setInterval` to avoid polluting the original code, yet easily see the variables value).

Comment: It works when I want to update a <p> for example, but I want to retrieve what the user entered . The best thing would be to retrieve the value when the user press the return key for example.

Comment: Well then, you need to say so :) Maybe the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$(this).prop("value")`

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
    alert($(this).prop("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="url" name="input1" value="https://myWebApplication.com/logs/">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLewqzqd/

Comment: I used the event .change instead of .on as mentioned by @Daniel Flint